# Yosemite updates and prompts

Tags: macos

I am very new to using Macbook Pro, and was recommmend finding on the new Yosemite system that there are far too many prompts and synched uppdates etc.
Does anyone know how I can do a general disabling of them?
For example, I would like to remove the prompt like auto refill, when I am filling in forms for payments or I get email and facebook uppdates when I am in other apps.

Answer (score 1):

Open System Preferences and choose Notifications. From there you can silence the ones you don’t want.